# Singular point of $f(z)$ also a singular point of $1/f(z)$ and $f^{2}(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, singularity

Suppose $z_{0} \in \mathbb{C}$ is an isolated singular point of the function $f$ of a given type (removable, pole of order $N$, essential). I need to show that $z_{0}$ is an isolated singular point of

1. $g(z) = 1/f(z)$ (here, additionally, assume that $f(z)$ has no zeros in some deleted neighborhood of $z_{0}$).
2. $h(z) = f^{2}(z)$

and find its type in each case.

I've been struggling with this problem for a couple of days - I tried using the neighborhood definition of an isolated singular point with $\delta$'s, but that wasn't getting me anywhere.

Could somebody please walk me through this problem? I'm extremely confused to the point of tearing my hair out. Maybe just a full solution for 1. and a hint for 2.?

Thanks.

Comment: You can get a picture of what's going on by considering $f(z) = \frac{\sin z}{z}$, $f(z) = z^{-n}$, and $f(z) = e^{1/z}$ in turn.

Comment: @Unit, I've already looked at several examples - did not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$ has no zeroes in some neighbourhood $U$ of $z$, then $f(U-\{z\})$ is some subset of $\mathbb C$ that does not contain $0$. The inversion $\iota: x \mapsto \frac1x$ is continuous (holomorphic if the set is open) on such a subset. This means that $\iota \circ f: U - \{z\} \to \mathbb C$ is holomorphic as a composition of holomorphic functions. But $(\iota \circ f)(x)$ is just $\frac1{f(x)}$. ($f(U-\{z\})$ is an open set since holomorphic maps map open sets to open sets).

So $\frac1{f(x)}$ is holomorphic on $U-\{z\}$ for some neighbourhood of $z$, this means the singularity is isolated.

In order to see what kind of singularity comes out start with the case of a pole.

1. Pole -  This means that you have a neighbourhood $U$ of $z$ so that on $U-\{z\}$ the function $f$ is of the form $f(x)=(x-z)^{-n} g(x)$ for some holomorphic function $g$ defined on all of $U$ and that is not zero in $U$. The inversion is $(\iota \circ f)(x)=(x-z)^n \frac1{g(x)}$ and is a priori defined only on $U-\{z\}$.

   But since $\frac1g$ is holomorphic and defined on all of $U$ (it has no zeros), and the polynomial $(x-z)^n$ also is holomorphic on all of $U$, the function $\frac1{f(x)}$ can be extended holomorphically by $\frac{(x-z)^n}{g(x)}$ onto all of $U$.
2. Removable - There are two subcases, either the value of the extension of $f$ at $z$ is $0$ or it is not $0$. If it is not $0$ then $f$ is the restriction of a holomorphic function $\tilde f: U \to \mathbb C$ that does not take the value $0$ on $U-\{z\}$. But then $\frac1{\tilde f}$ is holomorphic on $U$ and $\frac1f=\frac1{\tilde f}\large\lvert_{U-\{z\}}$ is extended by $\frac1{\tilde f}$ and the singularity is removable.

   If $\tilde f$ is the extension of $f$ onto $U$ and $\tilde f(z)=0$, then it is true that $\tilde f(x)=(x-z)^n g(x)$ where $g$ is holomorphic and does not have any zeros on $U$. This can be seen by considering the power series expansion of $\tilde f$ at $z$: $\tilde f(x)=\sum_k a_k (x-z)^k$. If $\tilde f(z)=0$ then $a_0=0$ and maybe some $a_k=0$ for $k\in\{0,..,n\}$ for some $n$. Thats why you can write $\tilde f(x)=(x-z)^n \sum_{k=n} a_k (x-z)^{k-n}$ with $a_n\neq 0$. At any rate this shows that $\tilde f$ can be put in the form $f(x)=(x-z)^n\ g(x)$ where $g(z)\neq 0$ and $g$ is holomorphic (it has an absolutely convergent power series) in some neighbourhood of $z$. By shrinking the domain even further you can assume $g$ is not zero anywhere in the domain. This means $\frac1{g}$ is holomorphic.

   Putting this part together $f(x)=\tilde f(x)\lvert_{U-\{z\}} = (x-z)^n g(x)$ with $g$ nonzero and holomorphic. So $\frac{1}{f(x)}=(x-z)^{-n}\frac{1}{g(x)}$ with $\frac1{g}$ being holomorphic at $z$ and non-zero. This means $\frac{1}f$ has a pole at $z$.
3. Essential - A singularity is essential if it is neither a pole or a removable singularity. Now we know that $\iota$ takes functions with poles at $z$ and makes them removable singularities. On the other hand it takes removable singularities and and makes them either poles or removable. Note now that $(\iota \circ \iota \circ f)=f$ on $U-\{z\}$. So if $\frac1f$ has a removable singularity or a pole at $z$, then $f=\frac1{1/f}$ has a removable singularity or a pole at $z$, ie it does not have an essential singularity.

   However since $\frac1f$ definitely has a singularity at $z$, if $f$ is essential so $\frac1f$ must also be essential.

For case (2) the same argument goes through, but you must use a function other than $\iota$.

Comment: what do you mean "the other case with a function other than $\iota$"? The grammar is not clear to me what you are asking me to do.

Comment: I meant you can use the same argument for case (2), but you must compose with a different function in the argument (not the inversion).

Comment: ok. But what kind of isolated singular point did you assume $f$ had so that its reciprocal would have a removable singularity? I thought you had to consider all three cases: $f$ has a removable singularity, $f$ has a pole of order $N$, $f$ has an essential singularity, and then see what happens to $1/f(z)$. It doesn't look like you did that here. Also, I'm not sure we have ever discussed holomorphic (analytic) maps...

Comment: I had mistyped, I definitely did not mean to write that the singularity is removable. Aside from that the argument doesn't care what kind of singularity is present. The only thing that matters is: outside of $z$, $f$ is a function of type $X$. Inversion is also a function of type $X$, as long as $0$ does not lie in the domain. The composition of two functions of type $X$ is of type $X$. So in a domain around (but not containing) $z$ chosen so it does not contain zeroes of $f$ you have $\iota \circ f$ is of type $X$.

Comment: and by type $X$, you mean?

Comment: Continuous, holomorphic, differentiable or whatever it is your are considering in your course. (Of course you would need to verify that inversion is of that type if it is not immediate)

Comment: yes, I believe I would need to. I do already have that composition of two holomorphic functions is holomorphic. And by inversion, you mean  of course  "1 over", not funciton inverses.

Comment: Yes, I mean the map $\iota$ defined above.

Comment: can't you just use the Cauchy-Riemann equations for that?

Comment: To show $\iota$ is holomorphic? Yes, or directly with the differential quotient, that also works and is less work.

Comment: I see that that argument doesn't care what kind of singularity is present, but I think the way the question was asked, it is important. Thank you, but I think this answer is really only useful to me if I wanted to prove that if $f(z)$ has a (generic) isolated singular point (of unspecified type) at $z_{0}$, then  $1/f(z)$ also has a (generic) isolated singular point (of unspecified type) at $z_{0}$, which really isn't what I'm supposed to do for this problem.

Comment: I see, I did not read the subpoint "and find its type in each case." Sorry about that, I will put in another part that analysis what kind of singularities can come out.

Comment: thank you!! That would really make my day! :)

Comment: For function 2, let's say that $z_0$ is essential. Then, this means the limit doesn't exist, or, the limit from the left and right sides are different. Suppose these were equal in absolute value though (for example, -2 and 2 for the left and right sides). Since your function squares these limits, they'll both end up going to 4. So, for $h(z)$, $z_0$ is removable if this happens, but if these limits are still different on each side, it's essential.

Comment: @s.harp for the second function, I actually didn't do it your way - I just expanded the Laurent series. It's not hard for that one.